# SWIG. Module for FreePascal. Case insensitive names

Tags: swig, freepascal

I am working on SWIG module for Free Pascal.
Pascal is case insensitive language. Symbol names are case insensitive.
Two different C names like AName and aName will be same ANAME in Pascal.
I know SWIG supports overloading. But case insensitivity is not really overloading. ( By the way Pascal supports overloading naturally. No need to rename overloaded functions in Pascal. )

What I need, for C AName and aName, SWIG should automatically create AName and aName_SWIG_1 in Pascal.

My current approach:

1. for each name (uppercased), I search through previous siblings on same level, that have same uppercased sym:name.
2. if N siblings found, I set SWIG_N to new attribute "sym:cisuffix"
3. when name is being generated for Pascal, I check if "sym:cisuffix" exists, and append it to a name.

Is there a better approach?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified approach. Instead of scanning on same node level, it scans in case insensitive cisymtab List, made from symtab at beginning.
cisymtab List is pupulated with nodes that are in same symtab.
Each node, also is added by following attributes: 
"pascal:ciname" (uppercased syn:name); "pascal:cinumber" (1,2...etc), and "pascal:cisuffix" (i.e. "__SWIG_1")

I know it is not 100% reliable. For example, overridden virtual methods can be mistakenly named in descendant class. 
May be I will exclude virtual methods from this automatic CI resolution....

Any other ideas?